# Awk in loopwith different file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I have four files and want to run a awk code on each file. But this code is not working.

My code:

```
for i in "udp-250b.tr" "udp-50b.tr"
do
awk '
BEGIN {
    //some code
}
{  
    //some code
}
END {
   //some code
} ' i
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Awk` can work with multiple files no need of `for`

syntax will be like this

```
awk '{  }' file1 file2 file3
```

or

```
awk '{  }' file*
```

In your case

```
awk 'BEGIN{ } { } END{ }' udp-*.tr
```

> **To correct your existing code change**

```
} ' i
```

**To**

```
} ' "$i"
```

Comment: NO , I want to run code for each file separately . if i have four files , I want four outputs.

Comment: "awk '{  }' file1 file2 file3" this is not working.  Getting only one (may be combined) output

Comment: Through note that the behavior will be slightly different — in a loop the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks will be run for each file; putting all three in the same command the blocks will only be run once total. OP hasn't given us enough information to know which way he wants.

Comment: @prithviparre in awk you can pass through variable like this `awk -v myvar="$i" 'BEGIN{ print myvar }'`